# how to get the current page using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible that I can get the current page using javascript?

for example if I get to the home page of subpage, I will the the string name of `index.php` or if I go to the about page I can get the `about.php`.

I try this code :
`window.location.pathname`

but I got this in return in my subdomain.
 `/directory/new/index.php` and `/directory/new/about.php`

Does anyone have an idea about my case? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Simple `document.URL.match(/[^\/]+$/);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.href` or `top.location.href`
You will get "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678553/how-to-get-the-current-page-using-javascript" for this page.

```
`var url=window.location.href.split('/');
var name=url[url.length-1];`
```

name is the index.php or about.php

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

for /directory/new/index.php, split("/") will return [,"directory","new","index.php"], and pop() will return the last element index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **[document.URL](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp)**

```
document.URL
```

OR  **[window.location.href](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp)**

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: They do not spit out the current file name, only the full URL

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly get what you want, Try like this:

```
var segments = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var result = segments[segments.length - 1];
```

Here is data about current question url:

```
hash: "#13678603"
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678553/how-to-get-the-current-page-using-javascript/13678603#13678603"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/13678553/how-to-get-the-current-page-using-javascript/13678603"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
```